# Need a fuction to remove specific caracters from a string,

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, tuples

I need help to do a function that, for example:

You have a string called x

```
x = "[(2,3), {4,5}, [6,7], np.array([(2+3)*5])"
```

And what I want is to remove all caracters from the string that are not the following caracters: `"(" ")" "[" "]" "{" "}"`

So in this specific example the ideal output is: `x = "[(){}[]([)]"`

Comment: What have you tried? Please include your code.

Comment: Thanks for helping me but I have the answer now!

Answer (score 1):

just keep the characters you want to keep by filtering them using a `set` (for speed) and rebuild the string with `str.join` from the list of characters.

```
s = "[(2,3), {4,5}, [6,7], np.array([(2+3)*5])"

allowed = set("{}[]()")

new_s = "".join([x for x in s if x in allowed])
```

result:

```
>>> new_s
'[(){}[]([()])'
```

Comment: i didn't understand what ("".join) does :( Does it creates a string with the elements of the other string that are filtered by the set("{}[]()")? Thanks a lot for explaning this!!!!!!!!

Comment: if it works for you you can consider accepting the answer.